# Did GDAL 2.0 change how Python creates ESRI Shapefiles?

Tags: python, gdal

The [migration guide for GDAL 2.0](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/branches/2.0/gdal/MIGRATION_GUIDE.TXT) says:

> C++ API:
>
> - OGRSFDriverRegistrar and OGRSFDriver are now deprecated. Use
>     GDALDriverManager
>     and GDALDriver instead.

I have only ever used GDAL Python bindings, so I'm not sure how or if this affects any code I write. I used to create ESRI Shapefiles like this:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
```

Is this related to an `OGRSFDriver`? I tried to do

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
```

Which returns a driver but does not have any `CreateDataSource` binding in it.

Is it correct to continue to use the `ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')` convention for GDAL 2.0+? If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL and OGR are still separate packages after the migration so it is standard to use `ogr.GetDriverByName()` when creating/opening vector data.